# 'Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a datetime'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am currently getting this error when trying to select a date from a drop down list, once the date is selected it should Display data in a GridView depending on the drop down list value. This is achieved using a 'Where' statement equals the value of the selected index.

I understand that it is a problem with the way the dates are being displayed in the drop down list, as opposed to the way they are saved in the database. So I have tried to swap the format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd in the drop down list, to see if this fixes the problem. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Please can someone recommend a fix to this?

Drop Down List selected index change C# :

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sener, EventArgs e)
    {
        String query = "SELECT Stock_Take.Username, Item.ItemID, Item.ItemDesc, Stock_Take_Item.BarQuantity, Stock_Take_Item.StorageQuantity, Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew FROM Item INNER JOIN Stock_Take_Item ON Item.ItemID = Stock_Take_Item.ItemID INNER JOIN Stock_Take ON Stock_Take_Item.StockTakeIDNew = Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew where Stock_Take.Username = @USER AND Stock_Take.StockDate = @DATE";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
       // DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString());
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();


    }
```

Binding the dates from the database to the drop down list C# code:

```
private void BindDropDownList2(String field)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            String Query = "Select StockDate, StockTakeIDNEW from Stock_Take WHERE Username = @Value1";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", field);

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlDa.Fill(dataTable);
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDownList2.DataSource = dataTable;
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = "StockDate";
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = "StockTakeIDNew";
               // DropDownList2.DataTextFormatString = "(yyyy/MM/dd}";
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Fetch Error";
            msg += ex.Message;
```

*I also have another drop down list, that a user selects a Username from, which in turn affects what dates are shown in the DropDownList2

Comment: What is the value of `DropDownList2.SelectedValue`? What line is throwing `'Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a datetime'`?

Comment: The value is a datetime and the line throwing the error is 'SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();'

Comment: What is the value of `DropDownList2.SelectedValue.GetType()`? _Don't guess, actually run it and check._

Comment: @mjwills The value is '13/04/2018 00:00:00' (The date chosen from the drop down list. And the type is a String

Comment: @fredbrass were you able to identify the root cause and fix it? I'm facing similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
```

manually parse the value first, so it is a `DateTime`:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedValue); // TODO: replace with format etc
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have tried this code, and plus some formatting. However now it's throwing the error on the parse line 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' The line looks like this : ' var date = DateTime.ParseExact(DropDownList2.SelectedValue, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", null); ' Any recommendations to change this?